# Prove that $\displaystyle\prod_{q\in \mathbb{Q}^{\times}}|q|=1$

Tags: analysis, infinite-product

Prove that $\displaystyle\prod_{q\in \mathbb{Q}^{\times}}|q|=1$.

I don't have a lot of experience working with infinite products, but I read a couple of theorems that say that absolute convergence of infinite products requires that $\prod1+|a_n|$ converges, and that $\prod1+|a_n|$ converges iff $\sum a_n$ converges.

Now $\sum_{q\in \mathbb{Q}^{\times}}|q|$ certainly does *not* converge, implying that my original product is not absolutely convergent.  Which leaves me with the problem of being unable to rearrange its terms.  But since I was never given an enumeration of my rationals to begin with, I'm a bit vexed as to how I should proceed.

Here is the link to the problem: [homework 2](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~alina/204/hw2.pdf) (problem 2).  I'm not in the class, just doing the homeworks.  I'm doing it for the $\mid \cdot \mid_{\infty}$ absolute value.  Which is supposed to be just the normal absolute value (according to homework 1).

Comment: Append \displaystyle to the back of the infinite product to make it look bigger and better.

Comment: @git gud thanks good tip

Comment: No problem. It works with sums (which you used) and limits too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've misstated the problem. For all $x\in\mathbb{Q}^\times$,
$$\prod_{p\text{ prime or }\infty}|x|_p$$
is an infinite product all but finitely many terms of which are 1, so it certainly converges.

**Hint:** Note that, if $x=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_n^{a_n}$ where the $p_i$ are primes and $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$, then
$$|x|_{p_i}=\frac{1}{p_i^{a_i}}$$
and that $|x|_p=1$ for all other primes.

Comment: Ohh ok! I get it, so it's for a fixed rational, and it's the absolute value that is running through all primes, is that correct?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly right (as long as you mean a fixed *nonzero* rational)!

Comment: I do! =] ok thanks everyone for the quick responses.

Comment: @Electro: That's correct, it is a product over the different $p$-adic absolute values together with the usual one.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem is that you're misinterpreting the problem. You don't want to show that the product over all elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $1$, you want to show that when you take a given element $x\in\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ and multiply it's absolute value for all possible absolute values on $\mathbb{Q}$, you get $1$.
For a hint, look at Zev's answer (considering the prime factorization of $x$).